# Who was the colleague that Erik was going to contact for help?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-2011

After S.H.I.E.L.D confiscates Jane's work in *Thor*, the researchers discuss what they'll do next.  Erik mentions two colleagues. The first is reasonably implied to be Bruce Banner, but who is the second colleague he mentions?

Transcribed from the film:

> **Jane** Who are these people?
>
> **Erik** I knew this scientist... a pioneer in gamma radiation. S.H.I.E.L.D showed up and... umm. He wasn't heard from again.
>
> **Jane** They're not going to do that to us. I'm going to get everything back.
>
> **Erik** *mumbles* Please. Let me contact one of my colleagues. He's had some dealings with these people before. I'll email him and maybe he can help.
>
> **Darcy** They took your laptop, too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While no further mention is made of Erik's other colleague in the final film, [the original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html) reveals the identity to be Dr. Pym (presumably Hank Pym, the original Ant-Man).

> **JANE**
>
> (TO DARCY)
>    Will you please stop talking about
>    your iPod?!
>
> (TO SELVIG)
>    Who are these people?
>
> **SELVIG**
>
> No one knows much about them. But
>    I knew a scientist -- a pioneer in
>    gamma radiation. SHIELD showed up,
>    and he was never heard from again.
>
> **JANE**
>
> I'm not going to let them do this.
>    I'm getting everything back.
>
> **SELVIG**
>
> **Please, let me contact one of my
>    colleagues. Dr. Pym has had some
>    dealings with these people.** I'll e-
>    mail him and see if he can help.
>
> **DARCY**
>
> They took your laptop, too.

Comment: That would have been a **really** cool Easter Egg, especially now *Ant Man* has shown us that Hank Pym does in fact have dealings with SHIELD.

Answer (score 5):

Whilst the existing answer with the original script is perfectly clear in Erik referring to Bruce Banner and Hank Pym I have found the below interview where Feige clearly spells out it is those two.

> **Feige:  What are you remembering?**
>
> I think a few shots of the Destroyer and I was talking to [co-producer] Craig Kyle and he was mentioning to me that there might have been a reference to Hank Pym in the movie that might’ve been taken out.
>
> **Feige:  That scene is in the movie.  Literally the only thing we took out were the words “Hank Pym”.  It was when Selvig, Darcy, and Jane are on the roof and S.H.I.E.L.D.  has just taken all of their stuff.  Darcy is complaining about her laptop and Jane is going, “Who the hell are these guys anyway?”  Selvig then tells a story, which is clearly alluding to Bruce Banner, that he knew a gamma scientist and this thing happened and S.H.I.E.L.D. came up, which he had never heard of again.  Selvig may or may not have all of his facts straight on that, but those are the rumors that go around the science world there.  He goes, “I have a friend who has had experiences with these people.  Let me email him.”  That friend is Hank Pym.  But we took out “Hank Pym” because it felt like, “Banner! Hank!”  We were just like, “Enough.”**
>
> I think that this film is very strong with mentioning other things in the Marvel universe without hitting people over the head with it.
>
> **Feige:  Well, that reference we felt was one too many times over the head, which is why we pulled it out.**
>
> <sub>[Collider, Exclusive: Marvel’s Kevin Feige Talks THOR, AVENGERS, ANT-MAN, DOCTOR STRANGE, Animated Movies, Reveals What’s in Odin’s Vault (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150122102548/https://collider.com/kevin-feige-interview-thor-avengers-iron-man-3-ant-man-doctor-strange/88459/)</sub>

Answer (score -3):

The colleague is more likely Dr. Samuel Sterns. It's an easy jump to say Banner, but Sterns was studying the gamma radiation and, following his interaction with Blonsky in *The Incredible Hulk*, he becomes the Leader. Presumably, S.H.I.E.L.D. has him locked away. Banner - as the Hulk - might have disappeared, but he did so in an "escape" way, not a "disappeared by S.H.I.E.L.D." way.

Comment: I’ve found confirmation it was indeed Banner he was referring to here and not Sterns (writing an answer up). This is a nice theory and partial answer but unfortunately it is incorrect.